# Continuous function with a restriction is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

> Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function whose restriction to $(0,1]$ is continuous.
> Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable.

There are plenty of definitions, worked examples and explanations on inclusive boundaries i.e. $[a,b]$.

But because of the exclusive boundary I don't think I could use $0$ as an infimum.
Does the slight difference in the boundary make $f$ a non-uniformly continuous function?
If so, how do I prove this differently so the argument still holds?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: At a quick glance, I am not sure if there is easy theorem for you to recycle from. You may need to prove from first principle.

Comment: What tools do you have available? For example, this follows immediately from Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann-integrability (a bounded function on a compact interval is Riemann-integrable if and only if it's continuous almost everywhere), but I'm guessing you're not supposed to just cite that since then the problem would be trivial.

Comment: @Argyll Thanks for the edit of a (rather embarassing) typo, and yes I might have to come up with it myself by finding a walkaround.

Comment: @DanielHast My course textbook uses the method where you find a positive epsilon which is greater than U(f,P)-L(f, P), for a function f and a partition P and by the definition of uniform continuity, you can say that f is Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is bounded there exist $m,M$ such that $m \leqslant f(x) \leqslant M$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.  For any $\epsilon > 0$, take a point $x_1 \in (0,1)$ such that $(M-m)x_1 < \epsilon/2$.

For partition $P: 0< x_1< x_2< \ldots < x_n = 1$, let $M_j =\sup_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x)$ and $m_j =\inf_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x)$.

We have $(M_1-m_1)x_1 \leqslant (M-m)x_1 < \epsilon/2$, and

$$U(f,P) - L(f,P) = (M_1-m_1)(x_1-0) +  \sum_{j=2}^n(M_j-m_j)(x_j - x_{j-1})\\ < \epsilon/2 + \sum_{j=2}^n(M_j-m_j)(x_j - x_{j-1})$$

I'll let you finish by showing that the partition points $x_2,\ldots, x_{n-1}$ can be chosen such that

$$\sum_{j=2}^n(M_j-m_j)(x_j - x_{j-1}) < \epsilon/2$$

Comment: Thank you so much for a concise explanation! I was unsure about the partition bit but the rest of the argument looks familiar to me, so I should be able to work on the rest.

Comment: @krn08: You're welcome.